# What database table is the Magento Contact Us Email Options stored in?

Tags: database, magento, contactus

For an application I am writing, I need to know where some of the settings in the Admin Panel are being stored in a table on the database. Specifically, if one is logged into the Admin Panel, under <kbd>System</kbd>-><kbd>Configuration</kbd>-><kbd>Contacts</kbd>-><kbd>Email Options</kbd>, there are three select boxes "*Send Emails To*", "*Email Sender*" and "*Email Template*".

I can't seem to find what table the currently selected options are stored in. I want to do this since I am creating a transactional email via install script (I was able to find that transactional emails are stored under core_email_template), and would like it to be selected by default via my install script along with the default email being changed.I assumed that the currently selected options are somewhere on the database, I just can't seem to find where for the life of me!

I was hoping that someone would know where these settings were stored, or if someone could share some strategies to find out which table(s) hold information like this.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Sorry just found the answer, it was right in front of me the whole time. It seems that most admin settings are stored under core_config_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the core_config_data table